# Don't apply sort criteria by default

Tags: 7, views

I added sort criteria by price to my catalog view, and in the sort criteria I have only to option to use by default one of them - Ascending or Descending. But I don't want to use any sorting by price by default in catalog, I would like to apply it (one of the option Ascending or Descending) only after user chose an option and pressed button 'Apply' on the sort form. Is there any opportunity to do that?

Answer (score 2):

What would be removed from the directory by default sorting, you need to remove from Sort criteria. And leave the possibility of the sort only Filter criteria

Answer (score 2):

You would need to remove the sort criteria that you have added. Once you remove that, that only the expose filter would work and you would be able to sort the content on the basis of what the user has selected in the Expose filter.

Hope that this help.